# How to find what variable a value is assigned to?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, variables

I'm debugging on an old C# application.  There is a screen where I can click to run a query against a server and get a list of results.

The problem is that I'm having trouble figuring out how the results are computed.  Each result has a floating-point number associated with it that is displayed on the screen.  Suppose, for the sake of discussion, that the number next to the first result is 123.45.

I would guess that the number 123.45 must be assigned to a floating-point variable at some point, but if there are millions of lines of code, I have a lot of digging to do!

Therefore, I was wondering that if I'm certain that the number 123.45 is assigned to a variable at some point, is there some convenient way to find where it happens and what variable it is assigned to?  Is there a debugging tool that does this?

**Edit:** The commenters here are correct to point out that I don't know for sure that the number is assigned to a variable; I'm just guessing that it likely is.  Also, I'm familiar with setting conditions on breakpoints, but that won't help here because to set a breakpoint, you have to know what line the assignment occurs on.

My question here is whether or not there is a way to detect a particular value being assigned in an *unknown* place in the code to an *unknown* variable.  I want to find *where* the assignment occurs, and *which* variable it is assigned to.

**Second Edit:** Let's compare this to using the SQL profiler.  If I know that the value 123.45 is being inserted into a table or passed as a parameter to a stored procedure, I can use the SQL profiler and filter the command text for commands that contain the string "123.45".  That would likely find the exact command used to send 123.45 to the SQL server.  Is there something similar I can do if I'm looking for the value to be assigned to a C# variable, but I don't know which one?

I think that the answer is probably "no", but I thought someone here might be able to shed some light on this.

Comment: Doesn't *have* to be assigned to a 'variable'. Could be part of a UI element, for instance.

Comment: I assume you are familiar with the Condition you can set on a breakpoint?

Comment: Do you have the source? If so can you set a breakpoint and use the call stack?

Comment: In the native code debugger you seem to be able to break on state (of the CPU registers). You might be in for a long debug session but you can give it a try on a small test program first to see if that might work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543256(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: And [this channel9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-14-WinDbg-SOS) is hands-on with windbg and sos. There are more video's in that serie that might be worth watching.

Comment: Can you find the code that displays the value on the screen? Setting a breakpoint there should give you a good start on tracking down how it's calculated. I don't think there's anything built into VS that will do what you're after. It's almost like you need to inspect the stack after every operation and see if something got set to 123.45.

Answer (score 3):

If you can narrow it down to the different UI dispatchers that update your screen, you can add a condition that checks for that particular value, like this:

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I don't know that I can narrow it down in any such way.  The problem is that the application was written so that it is far more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a watch to it, if your in vs 2012? I am not sure if it is possible in your environment but set a breakpoint to the start of the method call that you want to find it. Right Click your variable, and click add watch and follow it on the bottom.

Comment: A watch list variable might be helpful if I knew which variable to watch, but in this case, I don't even know the name of the variable!

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer considering the two approaches are a different concept.

One possible solution to find it is to add a small method that does your check and programmatically breaks the debugging session using `Debugger.Break()`.

I'm afraid my WPF isn't very good so I have quickly simulated a datasource by simply adding values directly to `Control.Items`, through a little `event` handler which is invoked each time an item is added (so I simulate an `OnItemSourceChanged` event).

You should ofcourse use the built-in databound collection, but the concept is the same (if you have a working example with a "clean" approach, feel free to edit and add it).

Consider this example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> UpdateUI; 

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UpdateUI += sniff;

        PrintFromA();
        PrintFromB();
    }

    private void sniff(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstSample.Items.Contains(45))
        {
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }

    private void updateUI(int i)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            lstSample.Items.Add(i);
        });

        UpdateUI.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }


    private void PrintFromA()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i += 2)
        {
            updateUI(i);
        }
    }

    private void PrintFromB()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            updateUI(i);
        }
    } 
}
```

We're still checking if the value is 45, so `PrintFromB` should be the method we're looking for (`PrintFromA` will bypass it).

When we execute this, we can see that our code gets halted when `PrintFromB` is almost entirely executed, right at the point where 45 just got added.

Looking at the stacktrace, we see this:

> [image]

Now we can clearly see that we get this value from the `PrintFromB` method. Going to this point in the stacktrace will show you very clearly what variable is holding the value you're looking for.